# Hide certain image(s) when in mobile

Tags: css, html

So I am trying to hide two of the six user photos (the last two) when on a mobile/small screen. I know, I will use an @media code but what code would I write that would hide the last two photos?

The code on my site is quite extensive, so it would probably be easier to visit the page in question and use "inspect" to see the code. I have tried to hide the img(s) with some css code but it didn't work. So I have no idea what I am doing wrong!  **See the page in question @ Zoeaa.com**

Would really appreciate the help and feedback! 
If there is anything, I can do to improve this question, please let me know!

[Photo of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDerB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
//for screen size smaller than 768px (mobile)
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    //hide the last two list items
    .pop_members ul li:nth-last-child(-n+2) { 
        display:none; 
    }
}
```

This will hide the last two list items from the list when the screen size is smaller than 768px.

Comment: I tried using your code but it didn't work any ideas?

Comment: maybe you have other media class overriding this? try with display:none !important; not the best solution but give it a try.

Comment: I can see you have other media queries such as @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) that acts on the list items, this overrides other media queries.

Comment: It worked when I tried to inspect your website, your max-width: 900px is definitely overriding. Are you able to publish the code on to the website and show me where you put the code I showed you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this. I always use this method when I want to hide something on the webpage, with this you can hide any element you want

but it still depends to the structure of your code. there are many ways to hide an element. I hope this helps you!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    //Create Class that will only hide on mobile size.
    //Add the class desktop-only to the image(or LI) that you want to hide on mobile view.
    .desktop-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```